# What happens to unfinished goroutines when the main/parent goroutine exits or returns?

Tags: go, goroutine

I am reading the go programming language book and there is this example in Chapter 8.4

```
func mirroredQuery() string{
    responses := make(chan string, 3)
    go func() { responses <- request("asia.gopl.io") }()
    go func() { responses <- request("americas.gopl.io") }()
    go func() { responses <- request("europe.gopl.io") }()
    return <- responses // return the quickest response
}
```

There is also this comment

> Had we used an unbuffered channel, the two slower goroutines would have gotten stuck trying to send their responses on a channel from which no goroutine will ever receive.

This comment itself makes sense. But what happens to the two slow goroutines when `mirroredQuery` returns in the buffered case? Do they still run to finish or get cancelled?

**EDIT**: I understand that if the main goroutnine exits, then the 2 slower gorountines will 'evaporate' no matter they are running or not. But what if the main goroutine is still running, `mirroredQuery()` has already returned, would the 2 slow goroutines run to end? Basically, does `responses` still exist after `mirroredQuery` returns? If so, then it seems the 2 slow goroutines can finish in principle; if not, then we still have leakage just like the unbuffered case?

Comment: All goroutines terminate once they write to the channel. They may terminate after the calling function returns. If the channel was not buffered, two of them would *leak*.

Comment: @RedBlue: in the context of the topic line of this question, that's just wrong: the supposition is that this is called from the *main* goroutine so that returning causes the process as a whole to exit. It's true that they're not *canceled*, but they don't run to completion either. They just evaporate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the *main* goroutine returns, the entire runtime system quits, rather abruptly.  Hence any goroutines that are stuck waiting to send on an unbuffered or full channel simply ... cease to exist.  They're not *canceled*, nor do they run, nor do they wait.  [Think of it as the flash paper being set on fire.](https://youtu.be/b2zp_TQfzCo?t=103)

One can call this a goroutine leak, the same way one can refer to any resources (such as open files) not closed-or-freed before a program terminates a "leak".  But since the entire process terminates, there's nothing left.  There's no real *leak* here.  It's not a tidy cleanup, but the system does clean up.

[Here's a Playground link, as an example.](https://go.dev/play/p/tAVQqs_3Hpc)

(If you make use of things not defined by the Go system itself, you could get various leaks that way.  For instance, in the old System V Shared Memory world, you can create shared memory segments ([`shm_open`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open)) and if you never close and unlink them, they persist.  This is by design: they're meant to act a lot like files in a file system, except that they exist in memory, rather than on some sort of disk drive or whatever.  But this is far outside normal everyday Go programming.)

Re your edit: if the *main* goroutine has *not* exited, so that the program is still running, the other goroutines continue to run (or wait) until they run out of things to do and return themselves, or do something that causes them to exit (such as call [`runtime.Goexit`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#Goexit), or do something that causes a panic).  In this case, that's: wait for a response, then send the response into the channel, then return.  Assuming they get a response, they'll put the response into the channel.  Assuming that putting the response into the channel works (does not panic and not block), they will then return.  Having returned, they are done and they evaporate.  The channel itself persists and holds the strings: this is a resource leak, albeit a minor one, especially in a toy program.

If there are no references left *to* the channel itself, the channel itself will be garbage-collected, along with the strings in it; this cleans up the leaked resources.  Since we assume that `mirroredQuery` has returned, and that at this point the *last* of the spun-off goroutines has *also* returned, that's the last reference to the channel, so now the channel can be GCed.  (Whether and when this happens is up to the runtime.)  Until the *last* of these goroutines finishes, there's still at least one reference to the channel, preventing the channel (and hence the strings) from being GCed.

Had the channel been *unbuffered*, the two "losing" goroutines would block in the attempt to send into the channel.  That would cause those goroutines to remain, which in turn would cause the channel to remain, which in turn would cause the resources to remain allocated until the program as a whole terminates.  So that would be "bad".

Had `mirroredQuery` *closed* the channel, the two "losing" goroutines could attempt to send on a *closed channel*, which would cause them to invoke the panic code, which would kill the program.  That too would be "bad".  The *simplest* code that achieves the desired result is to make the channel buffered.

Should one of the goroutines wait (for a response) for several years, that would hold those "leaked" resources for all those years.  That would also be "bad" (slightly), so we'd want to make sure that they don't wait *forever*.  But that's impractical in a small demonstration program.

Comment: When I try example, "europe.gopl.io" always get printed out, and it is the third one. Any resson why it is not "asia.gopl.io" (first one)?

Comment: @pifuegtq23: the Go Playground runtime is limited by a simulator that runs only one goroutine at a time, and behaves in a completely deterministic fashion. The goroutines are, on that system, being added in reverse order of creation so the third one runs first. (The simulator and limitations exist specifically so that the server that runs the Go Playground can't be abused.) Try running the sample on your own multi-processor system.